# Prove the existence of a row and a column in the Boolean matrix which satisfy the conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"Let A be an 8x8 Boolean matrix. If the sum of A = 51, prove that there is a row and a column such that when the total entries of the row and column are added, the sum is greater than 13."

- I have started with the idea that a sum of 51 implies that there are 13 0s to be placed in the matrix. Every selection of a row and a column results in the selection of 15 boxes. For the sum of this selection to be less than or equal to 13, there must be at least 2 0s in the selection. But other than drawing out the matrix and experimenting with placing the 0s, I'm unsure of how to prove this elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** There is a column whose sum is at least 7.

**Hint:** There is a row whose sum is at least 7.

**Hint:** Combine the two.

Comment: So is it true that there is both a column and a row whose sum is at least 7 because there is no way to place the 0s in such a way that they all have a sum < 7? Is that sufficient enough for an answer?

Comment: Suppose all rows had sum $\le 6$.  What could you say about the total sum?